# How to use Matlab's interp1 with linear interpolation and clip extrapolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation, linear-interpolation, extrapolation

From the documentation of Matlab's [`interp1`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html), it seems that the method used for interpolation and extrapolation should be the same. However, I would like to implement a linear interpolation with clip extrapolation (hold extreme values). Is this possible using the `interp1` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't do it directly from the `interp1` function:

> Extrapolation strategy, specified as the string, 'extrap', or a real
>   scalar value.
>
> - Specify 'extrap' when you want interp1 to evaluate points outside the
>     domain using the same method it uses for interpolation.
> - Specify a scalar value when you want interp1 to return a specific constant value
>     for points outside the domain.

but I guess it's not too hard to implement yourself:

```
function vq = LinearInterpWithClipExtrap(x,v,xq)

    vq = interp1(x,v,xq);

    [XMax, idxVMax] = max(x);
    [XMin, idxVMin] = min(x);

    idxMax = xq > XMax;
    idxMin = xq < XMin;

    vq(idxMax) = v(idxVMax);
    vq(idxMin) = v(idxVMin);

end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `vq(idxMin) = v(1)` and `vq(idxMax) = v(end)` instead of `= max(x)` and `= min(x)` ?

Comment: Indeed. That's how I do it.

Comment: @CitizenInsane I'm not sure if that's right either because `x` doesn't have to be monotonically increasing... so you might not end up clipping at `v(1)` for the minimum. I've made a correction, not 100% of it either though.

Comment: Yes it's more generic this way, thought `interp1` was requiring for monotonic `x`, but it's `interp1q` which requires this.